# The maximal (special) unitary subgroup contained in the Spin group: $Spin(2N)\supset U(N) \supset SU(N) ?$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces, spin-geometry

1. Is it true that given a Spin group $Spin(2N)$, the maximal special unitary subgroup that it can contain is $SU(N)$? So
   $$
   Spin(2N) \supset SU(N)?
   $$
2. Is it true that given a Spin group $Spin(2N)$, the maximal unitary subgroup that it can contain is $U(N)$?
   $$
   Spin(2N) \supset U(N)?
   $$
   I think the 1. is true but the 2. is false. But how to prove or disprove them?

Because $(6)=(4)$, we may distinguish the case $N>4$, and $N<4$. I am mostly interested in the case $N>4$.

Some useful resources:

- Pierre Deligne in his [Notes on spinors](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/deligne.pdf)
- [Spin representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_representation)

Comment: Check out the wikipedia page on Borel- de Siebenthal theory.  2 is true.  1 is probably true, at least for large enough $N$

Comment: Thanks for Borel- de Siebenthal theory... Sorry if 2 is true, then 1 must be true (because ()⊃()). But I thought it is the other way around... 1 is true. 2 is false

Comment: No, if $SU(n)$ fits in $Spin(2k)$, it doesn't follow that $U(n)$ does.  For example, when $N=3$, $Spin(6) = SU(4)$ contains $SU(4)$, but not $U(4)$.

Comment: I improved my question - thanks for comments